# Can not drag file from local pc and drop on web page using python and selenium

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I need drag file from my local pc and drop it on area on the web page
.send.keys('file_path') does not work.

```
drag_drop_area = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='root']/main/div[3]/section[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div")
file = '/home/new/Desktop/CT_filters/Braid-s.png'

drag_drop_area.send_keys(file)
```

what is interesting place where I want to drag and drop file looks
[image]
and after run code looks like
[image]
Looks like some action was perform because field is highlighted

Comment: Which website is it? Also try the full absolute path of the file to the input tag.

Answer (score 0):

To upload a file from your PC with Selenium the best approach is to send the file path + name as a string to the appropriate element on the web page. This will not be an element you graphically clicking as a user with mouse rather some other element, normally located by this XPath:

```
//input[@type='file']
```

To give you more precise answer we need to see the actual web page HTML.

Comment: I do not fully understand. It is full path to the image '/home/new/Desktop/CT_filters/Braid-s.png'. 
Web page element html:
<div tabindex="0" class="file-drop_dropzone__upload_space__2ggcU"><svg id="Group_803" data-name="Group 803" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="53.172" height="53.172" viewBox="0 0 53.172 53.172" class="file-drop_dropzone__upload_space_icon__2bbgE"><path id="Path_148" data-name="Path 148" d="M0,0H53.172V53.172H0Z" fill="none"></path><path id="Path_149" data-name="Path 149" d="M14,3V15.163A3.041,3.041,0,0,0,17.041,18.2H29.2" transform="translate(18.967)" fill="none

Comment: Try reading what I wrote you.